# where to Manually edit the event name in this particular calendar made in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found this template in codepen and would like to understand where to add the event name manually seems like the event is repeating automatically and would like to understand where I can manually put the events without making it appear on other months

This is the link to script https://codepen.io/peanav/pen/ulkof/

```
 !function() {

  var today = moment();

  function Calendar(selector, events) {
    this.el = document.querySelector(selector);
    this.events = events;
    this.current = moment().date(1);
    this.draw();
    var current = document.querySelector('.today');
    if(current) {
      var self = this;
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        self.openDay(current);
      }, 500);
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.draw = function() {
    //Create Header
    this.drawHeader();

    //Draw Month
    this.drawMonth();

    this.drawLegend();
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawHeader = function() {
    var self = this;
    if(!this.header) {
      //Create the header elements
      this.header = createElement('div', 'header');
      this.header.className = 'header';

      this.title = createElement('h1');

      var right = createElement('div', 'right');
      right.addEventListener('click', function() { self.nextMonth(); });

      var left = createElement('div', 'left');
      left.addEventListener('click', function() { self.prevMonth(); });

      //Append the Elements
      this.header.appendChild(this.title); 
      this.header.appendChild(right);
      this.header.appendChild(left);
      this.el.appendChild(this.header);
    }

    this.title.innerHTML = this.current.format('MMMM YYYY');
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawMonth = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.events.forEach(function(ev) {
     ev.date = self.current.clone().date(Math.random() * (29 - 1) + 1);
    });


    if(this.month) {
      this.oldMonth = this.month;
      this.oldMonth.className = 'month out ' + (self.next ? 'next' : 'prev');
      this.oldMonth.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
        self.oldMonth.parentNode.removeChild(self.oldMonth);
        self.month = createElement('div', 'month');
        self.backFill();
        self.currentMonth();
        self.fowardFill();
        self.el.appendChild(self.month);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          self.month.className = 'month in ' + (self.next ? 'next' : 'prev');
        }, 16);
      });
    } else {
        this.month = createElement('div', 'month');
        this.el.appendChild(this.month);
        this.backFill();
        this.currentMonth();
        this.fowardFill();
        this.month.className = 'month new';
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.backFill = function() {
    var clone = this.current.clone();
    var dayOfWeek = clone.day();

    if(!dayOfWeek) { return; }

    clone.subtract('days', dayOfWeek+1);

    for(var i = dayOfWeek; i > 0 ; i--) {
      this.drawDay(clone.add('days', 1));
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.fowardFill = function() {
    var clone = this.current.clone().add('months', 1).subtract('days', 1);
    var dayOfWeek = clone.day();

    if(dayOfWeek === 6) { return; }

    for(var i = dayOfWeek; i < 6 ; i++) {
      this.drawDay(clone.add('days', 1));
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.currentMonth = function() {
    var clone = this.current.clone();

    while(clone.month() === this.current.month()) {
      this.drawDay(clone);
      clone.add('days', 1);
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.getWeek = function(day) {
    if(!this.week || day.day() === 0) {
      this.week = createElement('div', 'week');
      this.month.appendChild(this.week);
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawDay = function(day) {
    var self = this;
    this.getWeek(day);

    //Outer Day
    var outer = createElement('div', this.getDayClass(day));
    outer.addEventListener('click', function() {
      self.openDay(this);
    });

    //Day Name
    var name = createElement('div', 'day-name', day.format('ddd'));

    //Day Number
    var number = createElement('div', 'day-number', day.format('DD'));


    //Events
    var events = createElement('div', 'day-events');
    this.drawEvents(day, events);

    outer.appendChild(name);
    outer.appendChild(number);
    outer.appendChild(events);
    this.week.appendChild(outer);
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawEvents = function(day, element) {
    if(day.month() === this.current.month()) {
      var todaysEvents = this.events.reduce(function(memo, ev) {
        if(ev.date.isSame(day, 'day')) {
          memo.push(ev);
        }
        return memo;
      }, []);

      todaysEvents.forEach(function(ev) {
        var evSpan = createElement('span', ev.color);
        element.appendChild(evSpan);
      });
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.getDayClass = function(day) {
    classes = ['day'];
    if(day.month() !== this.current.month()) {
      classes.push('other');
    } else if (today.isSame(day, 'day')) {
      classes.push('today');
    }
    return classes.join(' ');
  }

  Calendar.prototype.openDay = function(el) {
    var details, arrow;
    var dayNumber = +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].innerText || +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].textContent;
    var day = this.current.clone().date(dayNumber);

    var currentOpened = document.querySelector('.details');

    //Check to see if there is an open detais box on the current row
    if(currentOpened && currentOpened.parentNode === el.parentNode) {
      details = currentOpened;
      arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');
    } else {
      //Close the open events on differnt week row
      //currentOpened && currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
      if(currentOpened) {
        currentOpened.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
          currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
        });
        currentOpened.addEventListener('oanimationend', function() {
          currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
        });
        currentOpened.addEventListener('msAnimationEnd', function() {
          currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
        });
        currentOpened.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
          currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
        });
        currentOpened.className = 'details out';
      }

      //Create the Details Container
      details = createElement('div', 'details in');

      //Create the arrow
      var arrow = createElement('div', 'arrow');

      //Create the event wrapper

      details.appendChild(arrow);
      el.parentNode.appendChild(details);
    }

    var todaysEvents = this.events.reduce(function(memo, ev) {
      if(ev.date.isSame(day, 'day')) {
        memo.push(ev);
      }
      return memo;
    }, []);

    this.renderEvents(todaysEvents, details);

    arrow.style.left = el.offsetLeft - el.parentNode.offsetLeft + 27 + 'px';
  }

  Calendar.prototype.renderEvents = function(events, ele) {
    //Remove any events in the current details element
    var currentWrapper = ele.querySelector('.events');
    var wrapper = createElement('div', 'events in' + (currentWrapper ? ' new' : ''));

    events.forEach(function(ev) {
      var div = createElement('div', 'event');
      var square = createElement('div', 'event-category ' + ev.color);
      var span = createElement('span', '', ev.eventName);

      div.appendChild(square);
      div.appendChild(span);
      wrapper.appendChild(div);
    });

    if(!events.length) {
      var div = createElement('div', 'event empty');
      var span = createElement('span', '', 'No Events');

      div.appendChild(span);
      wrapper.appendChild(div);
    }

    if(currentWrapper) {
      currentWrapper.className = 'events out';
      currentWrapper.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
        currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
        ele.appendChild(wrapper);
      });
      currentWrapper.addEventListener('oanimationend', function() {
        currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
        ele.appendChild(wrapper);
      });
      currentWrapper.addEventListener('msAnimationEnd', function() {
        currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
        ele.appendChild(wrapper);
      });
      currentWrapper.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
        currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
        ele.appendChild(wrapper);
      });
    } else {
      ele.appendChild(wrapper);
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawLegend = function() {
    var legend = createElement('div', 'legend');
    var calendars = this.events.map(function(e) {
      return e.calendar + '|' + e.color;
    }).reduce(function(memo, e) {
      if(memo.indexOf(e) === -1) {
        memo.push(e);
      }
      return memo;
    }, []).forEach(function(e) {
      var parts = e.split('|');
      var entry = createElement('span', 'entry ' +  parts[1], parts[0]);
      legend.appendChild(entry);
    });
    this.el.appendChild(legend);
  }

  Calendar.prototype.nextMonth = function() {
    this.current.add('months', 1);
    this.next = true;
    this.draw();
  }

  Calendar.prototype.prevMonth = function() {
    this.current.subtract('months', 1);
    this.next = false;
    this.draw();
  }

  window.Calendar = Calendar;

  function createElement(tagName, className, innerText) {
    var ele = document.createElement(tagName);
    if(className) {
      ele.className = className;
    }
    if(innerText) {
      ele.innderText = ele.textContent = innerText;
    }
    return ele;
  }
}();

!function() {
  var data = [
    { eventName: 'Lunch Meeting w/ Mark', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' },
    { eventName: 'Interview - Jr. Web Developer', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' },
    { eventName: 'Demo New App to the Board', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' },
    { eventName: 'Dinner w/ Marketing', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' },

    { eventName: 'Game vs Portalnd', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue' },
    { eventName: 'Game vs Houston', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue' },
    { eventName: 'Game vs Denver', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue' },
    { eventName: 'Game vs San Degio', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue' },

    { eventName: 'School Play', calendar: 'Kids', color: 'yellow' },
    { eventName: 'Parent/Teacher Conference', calendar: 'Kids', color: 'yellow' },
    { eventName: 'Pick up from Soccer Practice', calendar: 'Kids', color: 'yellow' },
    { eventName: 'Ice Cream Night', calendar: 'Kids', color: 'yellow' },

    { eventName: 'Free Tamale Night', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green' },
    { eventName: 'Bowling Team', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green' },
    { eventName: 'Teach Kids to Code', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green' },
    { eventName: 'Startup Weekend', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green' }
  ];



  function addDate(ev) {

  }

  var calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', data);

}();
```

Comment: `Calendar.prototype.renderEvents` is where event rendering is happening and data is there in `data` array and the color is applying randomly in ` Calendar.prototype.drawMonth`. based on the color , event is added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the event for a fixed date you can also modify as below:

1.Change **this.events.forEach** as below:

```
this.events.forEach(function(ev) {
     //ev.date = self.current.clone().date(Math.random() * (29 - 1) + 1);
     ev.date =moment(ev.date);
    });
```

2.Change data as:

```
 var data = [
    { eventName: 'Lunch Meeting w/ Mark', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' ,date:'2018-07-27'},
    { eventName: 'Interview - Jr. Web Developer', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange',date:'2018-06-28' },
    { eventName: 'Demo New App to the Board', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange',date:'2018-06-29' },
    { eventName: 'Dinner w/ Marketing', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange',date:'2018-06-30' }
    ];
```

Comment: will this work? var data = [
    { 
    eventName: 'Lunch Meeting w/ Mark',
    calendar: 'Work', 
    backgroundImage: "url('http://pngimg.com/uploads/wine/wine_PNG9486.png')" ,
    date:'2018-07-27'
    },

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify below code inside **Calendar.prototype.drawMonth** function:

```
this.events.forEach(function(ev) {
   ev.date = self.current.clone().date(Math.random() * (29 - 1) + 1);
});
```

This is the flow of the code

1. Intialize Calender which calls **this.draw();**

   ```
   function Calendar(selector, events) {
      this.el = document.querySelector(selector);
      this.events = events;
      this.current = moment().date(1);
      this.draw();
      var current = document.querySelector('.today');
      if(current) {
        var self = this;
           window.setTimeout(function() {
             self.openDay(current);
           }, 500);
       }
   }
   ```

   2.**Calendar.prototype.draw** call to **this.drawMonth();**

   ```
   Calendar.prototype.draw = function() {
    //Create Header
    this.drawHeader();

    //Draw Month
    **this.drawMonth();**

    this.drawLegend();
   }
   ```

   3. Inside the **drawMonth** function  ***this.events.forEach***  loop assigned the data to random dates of current month.

      `Calendar.prototype.drawMonth = function() { 
      var self = this;
      this.events.forEach(function(ev) {
         ev.date = self.current.clone().date(Math.random() * (29 - 1) + 1);
      });
      }`

Comment: Hope it wouldn't be much but can you please give an example of the script I need to add, say I want to add June 30 event  ev.date = self.current.clone().date(Math.random() * (29 - 1) + 1);

Comment: this.events.forEach(function(ev) {
     //ev.date = self.current.clone().date(Math.random() * (29 - 1) + 1);
  ev.date =moment("2018-06-30");
  alert( ev.date);
    });
@Chrissa- if found useful upvote my answer

Comment: You can also do like this:

    this.events.forEach(function(ev) {
     //ev.date = self.current.clone().date(Math.random() * (29 - 1) + 1);
  ev.date =moment(ev.date);
    });

var data = [
    { eventName: 'Lunch Meeting w/ Mark', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' ,date:'2018-07-27'},
    { eventName: 'Interview - Jr. Web Developer', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange',date:'2018-06-28' },
    { eventName: 'Demo New App to the Board', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange',date:'2018-06-29' },
    { eventName: 'Dinner w/ Marketing', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange',date:'2018-06-30' }];